# Fake alert in Review Queues

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

That's probably a bug, but I still don't see what could be causing it.

I'm mostly active on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) (Apple Stack Exchange site) and I often check [the Review Queues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review) for new posts/suggested edits to verify. Just about now, when I was peacefully coming to see if there was something new, I saw that big red dot next to "Low quality posts". Of course, I know what this dot means: there are lots of pending reviews in this queue. So I went there to review the posts and I was surprised to see: "This queue has been cleared!". The following screenshot depicts the issue well I think:

[image: Screenshot of the Ask Different Low quality posts review queue empty while there's a red dot next to "Low quality posts" in the drop-down menu]

<sup>Image was cropped</sup>

Comment: There are lots of posts. You can't see them because you've acted on them. This is a duplicate from a long time ago, multiple times over.

Comment: Adding to @Nij correct info, the red dot is "global", it appears to anyone who can review without checking each user's past reviews to see how many items they can actually review.